# What is facebook's Page / Checkin Pagination limit on search?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I can't seem to find it in the documentation anywhere, and only seem to return 50 results when querying.

`https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=coffee&type=place&limit=100&offset=200`

Answer (score 1):

Any and all requests to Facebook's API has a default limit of 50. You can add a `limit=X` parameter to any request you make to the Graph API.

For example, to get 300 results from a users feed, you would use something like this:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/USER_ID/feed?limit=300
```

Comment: I added an example. Try that, even when authed in.